# PrimaryKey 'id' not set by auto incrementer

Tags: primary-key, realm, auto-increment

I wrote a static class that auto-increments the id of a RealmObject by 1.

```
public class AutoIncrementKey {

    public static int Next(Class<? extends RealmObject> c)
    {
        Realm realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
        Number maxId = realm.where(c).max("id");
        realm.close();
        if(maxId == null)
        { // no object exists, so return 0
            return 0;
        }
        return maxId.intValue() + 1;
    }

}
```

However, when I set the default value of  a RealmObject's ID like so:

```
@PrimaryKey private int id = AutoIncrementKey.Next(PresetSelect.class);
```

It never works! Specifically the first time it goes to create a new class via realm.createObject(IExtendRealmObject.class) the value is 0, but AutoIncrementKey.Next(...) returns the id as 1!

So id is never set to 1. It's always 0, and trying to create more objects causes it to throw an error "index already exists: 0"

What gives?

The AutoIncrementKey.Next() function IS being called. It IS finding the next key to be 1. The value returned simply isn't carried through though.

**Edit:**
So now that I've managed to create more than one object in my Realm, I'm finding that setting the id to a default value isn't the only issue.

Setting ANY member of a class extending RealmObject with a default value is IGNORED. Whats the deal with that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because instead of

```
realm.createObject(IExtendRealmObject.class)
```

You're supposed to use

```
realm.createObject(IExtendRealmObject.class, primaryKeyValue)
```

---

But I think your method

```
public class AutoIncrementKey {

    public static int Next(Class<? extends RealmObject> c)
    {
        Realm realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
        Number maxId = realm.where(c).max("id");
        realm.close();
        if(maxId == null)
        { // no object exists, so return 0
            return 0;
        }
        return maxId.intValue() + 1;
    }

}
```

Would be more stable as

```
public class AutoIncrementKey {
    public static int Next(Realm realm, Class<? extends RealmModel> c)
    {
        Number maxId = realm.where(c).max("id");
        if(maxId == null)
        { // no object exists, so return 0
            return 0;
        }
        return maxId.intValue() + 1; // why not long?
    }
}
```

If you meet the condition that **when you call `AutoIncrementKey.Next(realm, Some.class)`, then a write transaction is in progress.**

Hell, you might even add

```
public class AutoIncrementKey {
    public static int Next(Realm realm, Class<? extends RealmModel> c)
    {
        if(!realm.isInTransaction()) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("Realm is not in a transaction.");
        }
        // continue as mentioned
```

It should work well for your needs

Comment: I'll give this a shot now. Also, no hard reason not to use a long for id, but the database will only contain a total of around 1000 objects anyways as the model is fixed. 4 presets with 8 channels each with 32 bands each.

Comment: Ok, so am I just unable to set default values for members of a realm object? I do: private Float level = DEFAULT_LEVEL; for the value of a Trim object, and level always returns null regardless.

Comment: Default value is not supported right now. See https://github.com/realm/realm-java/issues/777 @MagicMarbles

Comment: Man, constructor + field access not working with the Realm-Transformer seems to be a cause of a *lot* of headache lately

Comment: I'll have to make due with adding a SetDefaults method I suppose. On the upside I'll have a simple way to reset objects at least.